# Sharepoint 2010 Workflow: add task with List content

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I'm managing a Sharepoint list, which is holding all our changes made in our last software iteration. Among the fields are a few pertaining to the testing process, for example a 'Testing Result' dropdown (possible values Ok/Not Ok/Todo).

I've successfully set up a Sharepoint Workflow, which assigns a "Please test this" Task to the developers, when someone sets this 'Testing result' to 'Not Ok'. This works nicely, but I would like to add some fields from the List to the Task title, to let the developers know which item they actually need to re-test.

Is this possible? I'm using Sharepoint Designer for this (it's a Sharepoint 2010 workflow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this myself, you can add all necessary fields if you use the action 'Custom Task Process' instead of simply assigning a task.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if you create a variable and build up a string and then assign it to the Title.
you string can be made up of static text, other workflow values and fields from the list you are working or from somewhere else in the site.